# can't delete a folder after spawn process is closed

Tags: node.js

I spawn a process (child process) that works on a folder, after the process it's closed if I try to delete the folder manually it says that I don't have the right permission to delete it

Answer (score 0):

There must be permissions issue, Try this programmatically,

```
fs.rmdirSync(dir, { recursive: true });
```

Comment: i'm not trying to delete it, it's just "blocked" I can do nothin

Comment: Oh okay. But, that's weird!

Comment: yeah it seems like the process it's not closed

Comment: i'm making an electron app and if I update the page it works

Answer (score 0):

@Gianmarco
Try this logic to kill the child process:

```
var psTree = require('ps-tree');

var kill = function (pid, signal, callback) {
    signal   = signal || 'SIGKILL';
    callback = callback || function () {};
    var killTree = true;
    if(killTree) {
        psTree(pid, function (err, children) {
            [pid].concat(
                children.map(function (p) {
                    return p.PID;
                })
            ).forEach(function (tpid) {
                try { process.kill(tpid, signal) }
                catch (ex) { }
            });
            callback();
        });
    } else {
        try { process.kill(pid, signal) }
        catch (ex) { }
        callback();
    }
};
```